# Export image collection to pixel value across bands

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, features, multi-band

I am trying to export an image collection to a 2D table where :

- axis 0 are pixels over the collection
- axis 1 are bands from the image collection

I would loose spatial information, as pixels would be unordered which is OK. It could look like this (pixel Id unecessary):

[image: example of table]

I found the function toArray() that seems to do exactly what I want, but I am unable to export it to a CSV file or any type of format

```
// Load a Landsat collection, select the bands of interest.
var imageCol = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  .select(['B1', 'B2', 'B3'])
  .filterDate('2017-09-01', '2017-09-02');

// Make an Array Image, with a 1-D Array per pixel.
var im_array = imageCol.toArray();
```

I have tried to transform this into a featureCollection but it doesn't work :

```
var im_feats = im_array.reduceToVectors()
```

I would have then export it in CSV with Export.table (it would be quite a heavy file):

```
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: im_feats ,
  description:'pix_bands',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Am I taking a wrong approach ? Is there a trick to get around this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very strange thing to do, but I'm sure you've got your reasons.

```
var pixels = image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 100
}) // A Dictionary with pixel values by band name

var numberOfPixels = ee.List(pixels.values().get(0)).size() // Pixel count for first band
var bandNames = image.bandNames()
var features = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfPixels.subtract(1))
    .map(function (i) {
      return bandNames.iterate(function (bandName, feature) {
        bandName = ee.String(bandName)
        var pixelValue = ee.List(pixels.get(bandName)).get(i)
        return ee.Feature(feature)
          .set(bandName, pixelValue)
      }, ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([0, 0])))
    })
) // Turn Dictionary into FeatureCollection
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/79d849a54ffecfb4a710a1d8a71dddd7

Comment: Thanks, this has worked for me. I have an alternative way I am using combining exporting tif from gee and data processing outside of gee (I do it in python). I was hoping the technique native to gee would be faster than the mixed one, but it is roughly 10 times slower.

Answer (score 0):

One easier way I found on one of the tutorials exports all the pixels out directly in Python very rapidly (see https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/intro-to-python-api-guiattard). The logic goes:

- Define area of interest using a `ee.Geometry()` object
- Perform "clipping" by doing `collection.getRegion(geometry, scale=4000).getInfo()`. Note that I inputted `scale=4000` to reduce the resolution, which you can also just ignore if you need the original image pixels. This returns a python list like this:

```
,
 ['2003_09_14',
  -92.86783407227614,
  42.059121602476,
  1063497600000,
  5729,
  3067],
 ...]
```

- Using the `ee_array_to_df()`, you can turn this long list into a data frame, which you could then save as a csv. This is more efficient in my opinion if you are planning to save multiple images (at different locations and times) at the same time.

**Minimum working example attached**

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ee 
# Trigger the authentication flow.
ee.Authenticate()

# Initialize the library.
ee.Initialize()

def ee_array_to_df(arr, list_of_bands):
    """Transforms client-side ee.Image.getRegion array to pandas.DataFrame.
    Modification of 
    https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/intro-to-python-api-guiattard
    """
    df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

    # Rearrange the header.
    headers = df.iloc[0]
    df = pd.DataFrame(df.values[1:], columns=headers)

    # Remove rows without data inside.
    df = df[['longitude', 'latitude', 'time', *list_of_bands]].dropna()

    # Convert the data to numeric values.
    for band in list_of_bands:
        df[band] = pd.to_numeric(df[band], errors='coerce')

    # Convert the time field into a datetime.
    df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ms')
    # Keep the columns of interest.
    df = df[['datetime', "longitude", "latitude", *list_of_bands]]

    return df
bands = ["NDVI", "EVI"]
date_start = "2003-04-01"
date_end = "2003-10-31"

collection = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1").filterDate(
        ee.Date(date_start), ee.Date(date_end)
    ).select(bands)

# this could also be user-defined
geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-92.9341420641855, 42.67007391984631],
          [-92.9341420641855, 41.94316737537707],
          [-92.0407572499231, 41.94316737537707],
          [-92.0407572499231, 42.67007391984631]]])

# now perform the clipping and dataframe conversion 
collection_area_of_interest = collection.getRegion(geometry, scale=4000).getInfo()
df_area_of_interest = ee_array_to_df(collection_area_of_interest, bands)

# to give you a preview
# df_area_of_interest.head()

# Plot the spatial map using the latitude and longitude (in practice, you need to pick specific date by doing df_area_of_interest[df_area_of_interest["datetime"]=="2003-06-10"]
plt.scatter(df_area_of_interest["longitude"], df_area_of_interest["latitude"], c=df_area_of_interest["NDVI"])
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]
[image]